# Adding a variable to the store upon a functional component's initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's assume we want a Counter component `<Counter startingValue={0}/>` that allows us to specify the starting value in props and simply increases upon onClick.

Something like:

```
const Counter = (props: {startingValue: number}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const variable = useSelector(store => store.storedVariable);

    return <p onClick={dispatch(() = > {storedVariable: variable})}>{variable}</p>;
}
```

Except, as it mounts, we'd like it to store its counting variable in the redux store (its value equal to the startingValue prop) and, as it unmounts, we'd like to delete the variable from the store.

Without the store, we could simply use the `useState(props.startingValue)` hook, however with the store it seems like we need constructors / equivalent.
A solution I see is to implement a `useState(isInitialRender)` variable and to create a variable in the store or not basing on an if instructor, albeit it looks like a bit convoluted solution to me.
I also get the feeling that I'm trying to do something against the react-redux philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is intended for. If you specify an empty array for the second argument (the dependency array) then it will only run on the first render, and you can use the return function to remove it.

Here's roughly how to do it:

```
const Counter = (props: {startingValue: number}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const variable = useSelector(store => store.storedVariable);
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({type: 'store-starting-value', payload: startingValue})
        return ()=>{
             dispatch({type: 'clear-starting-value'})
        }
    }, []);

   //...
```